# Kohonen SOM Maps in R Tutorial

Tags: r, resources, maps, som

I am simply looking for a good tutorial that will walk me through how to create a SOM in R.  I am reading Kohonen and Kaski's paper on using the maps to identify the structure of Welfare, and want to try the technique my self.

I think many of the examples in R have a lot to be desired.  I have looked on the web and didn't find anything that I thought made the process easy to understand.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few pointers:

- [SOM package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/som/)
- [Kohonen package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kohonen/)

Most of the SOM related packages are from the [Chemometrics and Computational Physics area](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ChemPhys.html), but you also have a look at [the cluster view on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html).

*Edit:* Incidentally, I'm not aware of any tutorials, but one good way to find examples [is to google with ext:r](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS291US308&q=som+ext:r&start=0&sa=N).  There are several "som" scripts that show up that way, including [this example which shows how to use it with GGobi](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~dicook/Army/multivariate.r).

Comment: Just for completeness, batchSOM in class package (part of the Venables & Ripley package bundle)

Answer (score 5):

Shane already mentioned the `kohonen` package. An introduction and tutorial can be found in the *Journal of Statistical Software*:
[Self- and Super-organizing Maps in R: The kohonen Package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i05)

Comment: I saw this too, and it is the closest that I have found to being a good tutorial.  Maybe it is wishful thinking, but I am hoping I can find a tutorial that is geared towards someone being introduced to the technique as well as how to perform the task in R, step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the [**CRAN package SOM**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/som/index.htm) ?

Comment: I did, but looking at the documentation with a few lines of code and no context is a little tough.

Answer (score 0):

GeoSpatial Data Mining course from [edugi](http://edugi.uni-muenster.de/eduGI/e-learning_courses.php) has pretty good materials.