# Kohonen package: Error in sample(1:nd, ng, replace = FALSE)

Tags: r, self-organizing-maps

I'm trying to run a supervised self-organiszing map to my expression data (ca 500 genes) for 23 samples.
The 23 samples are divided in 4 groups.
I would like to obtain maps of genes with similar expression patterns over these 4 groups.

When using the `xyf` function of the `Kohonen` package for supervized modeling,

```
data.xyf<-xyf(data,Y=annotation)
```

I run into the following error:

> Error in sample(1:nd, ng, replace = FALSE) :    cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

I can't find where to call `replace=T` in the function. There is no information on this topic in the package manual.

Comment: I'm no SOM expert, but it might be that you are trying to fit a too large model with not enough data. This SO question might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576075/kohonen-som-maps-in-r-tutorial

Answer (score 6):

You apparently have more cells than observations:
you can reduce the dimension of the grid (the default is 8*6)
as in the example in the documentation `?xyf`.

```
xyf(data, Y=annotation, grid=somgrid(3,2))
```